# How to filter data from various sheets based on dropdown selection

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am setting up a sheet to track renewable services for my company. There will be various tabs, for example, Domains, Hosting, Google Workspace and Phone Numbers.

I would like to be able to filter all data based on a dropdown that selects the company name and grabs all the data from each tab to display in one place.

See attached images for what I have so far. I am not experienced in using Google Sheets (or Excel) at all so any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is much easier to accomplish "the other way around": keep *all* the data in the same sheet and use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to decide which rows to show at a time.

This approach also has the benefit that you can directly edit the filtered results.